# Agenda (nodejs) schedule

Tags: node.js, agenda

I've been playing with https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda, which is nice way to queue / schedule things in node app, but I have a question.

What is the right syntax to schedule beerRun to run at exact time of exact day? The way written below does not really do the trick.

```
agenda.schedule('2017-01-07 7:27', 'beerRun', []);
```

In the agenda's documentation they have 'tomorrow at 7:30pm', which is good, but I need something else (exact day / time).

Comment: The documentation also says that they accept `Date` object as argument. Can you try to create a Date object with your values and pass it to the function ?

Comment: I just realised I was passing string instead of object.. thanks!